# break navigation buttons into two rows

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Just started learning CSS for a week now and I'm having an issue with this. I have a navigation bar at my footer but I want it to be responsive so that when it's in mobile mode, it will split into two rows of two buttons each (4 buttons total).

Trying to figure out how to do this for hours but can't seem to get working, not sure if it has to do with my button element but I do want to continue using this.

Here is my html code:

```html
<footer>
  <!-- include navigation buttons -->
  <nav id="navigation">
    <button class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">BACK</button>
    <button class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">MAP</button>
    <button class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">AREA</button>
    <button class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">NEXT</button>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

I'm also curious: if I want to edit the design of the button (the space between the buttons, the width of the buttons, etc. how am I supposed to do this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for this for this. in small screen 2 buttons will be in one line and in bigger screens they will all be in one line.

```html
<footer>
  <!-- include navigation buttons -->
  <nav id="navigation">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="nav-button col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">BACK</button>
      <button class="nav-button col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">MAP</button>
      <button class="nav-button col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">AREA</button>
      <button class="nav-button col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">NEXT</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```css
#navigation div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <!-- include navigation buttons -->
  <nav id="navigation">
    <div>
      <button class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">BACK</button>
      <button class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">MAP</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">AREA</button>
      <button class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">NEXT</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Also, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nyv7hfng/) fiddle.

> I'm also curious: if I want to edit the design of the button (the
>   space between the buttons, the width of the buttons, etc. how am I
>   supposed to do this?)

Look at `margin`, `padding`, `width`, `height` etc. These are all basic properties which are explained on the very first pages of each book about CSS.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried CSS `flex`?

there are many posibility with `flex`.

Check this [Example Code](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `<a>` instead of `<button>`...`href` is an attribute of `<a>` tag, not of `<button>`.

...and to achieve the result you can use **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)** (*It will also remove the spaces between your buttons*)

...and **[media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** rule for mobile screens

...and to style your link apply css to `.nav-button`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

a.nav-button {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  background: #ececec;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  a.nav-button {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <!-- include navigation buttons -->
  <nav id="navigation">
    <a class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">BACK</a>
    <a class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">MAP</a>
    <a class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">AREA</a>
    <a class="nav-button" href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">NEXT</a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```